# How the dialogflow voice chatbot end conversation

Tags: python-requests, dialogflow-es

I have done my Dialogflow voice conversation chatbot using python, But currently I am running the conversation chatbot using loop. So my conversation is running till the loop end. The cloud is developed by using webhook and dialogflow intent.

So how can I end the conversation once the chat is end in cloud to end notification in python application.

Comment: What framework are you using (flask, Django)? Where are you hosting your application (op-premise, which cloud)? can you give more information about the type of request, possibly  with examples

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This platform works best when you can illustrate exactly what you're doing and where you're having problems or exactly what errors you're getting. You've also said this is a "voice conversation" - is this Actions on Google or the Dialogflow Telephony integration? Please update your question to show the code you're currently using, along with as much other information as you can. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am not hosting this python code on any cloud. But I am using this code in a machine, The machine is developed using QT creator. So this QT application is calling my voice chatbot python application for each time. Then the base station python code is communicate with Google Dialogflow intent and webhook (node.js) will take care. So my question is, how to get the end conversation to python, from Google dialogflow intent and webhook node.js(cloud)?

Comment: def detect_intent_stream(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                         language_code, audio_config, session_client):
   
   try:
        requests = request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path)
        responses = session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)
    except:
        responses = "Could not get the detail at the moment, please try again"


        for response in responses:
                print('Intermediate transcript: "{}".'.format(
                    response.recognition_result.transcript))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following print in my python code, so there I have got the end_conversation intent, below I added the end_conversation log.

**print('Fulfillment text: {} \n'.format(query_result))**

End conversation log:


intent_detection_confidence: 1.0
diagnostic_info {
fields {
key: "end_conversation"
value {
bool_value: true
}
}